# How do I implement a yes/no into a text box in VB.net?

Tags: textbox

I am looking for when a button is pressed the user is asked yes or no if they want the button to continue it's function if yes it will, if no it will close the text box and nothing will happen.

Here is my current code (reset button for text fields):

```
Private Sub btnReset_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    txtDistanceInp.Clear() 
    txtOwnerInp.Clear()
    txtRegInp.Clear()
    txtSpeedLimitInp.Clear()
    txtTimeInp.Clear()
    txtTimeInp2.Clear()
End Sub
```

Any help offered is useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result As MessageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to continue?", "test", MessageBoxButton.YesNo)

    If result = MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
        MessageBox.Show("Go Ahead")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Dont go")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing happens when clicking the button, even after altering the code for VB?

Comment: Yes and it is not reseting the fields, any ideas?

Comment: I did't added the code to clear fields, Just show you how to get user confirmation, after that you can add txtDistanceInp.text = String.Empty to clear fields

Comment: Is there a possibility that you could convert the code to vb to me? It looks like c# if i'm correct. However, I also don't get any text box pop up.

Comment: I cannot find any online compiler, you can try to use Confirm() in vb